# How to pack Java Desktop Application made using eclipse with MySQL database with all the Data?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have made a JAVA Desktop Application using Eclipse and MySQL as a database. I want to use the application in another PC with all my created schema and data. How can I bundle or make an installation file so that it installs mysql with the required schema and the JAR file of my application into another pc?

Note: I know we can use embedded Database like H2, Sqlite but I want it to be done using MySQL only. So no suggestions on using other database for my application.

Comment: If you don't use an embedded database, then it'll be some clumsy hack you put together. "Real" databases aren't generally designed for such packaging, so what you want is a really bad idea. Embedded databases were designed for this exact use case.

Comment: You can pack the `DDL` and `DML` as separate `SQL` files and trigger them while deploying the build. But your database program itself, I think, cannot be packed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your application architecture but below point or solution could help you.

**Solution 1** :

You can create DDL for schema database and the insert data. Once your application successfully install, you just run the script to execute this DDL file. Can be done in automation installation script.

**Solution 2** :

You can dump mysql and restore to other PC. No worry about the structure, it completely clone from the original including data. Can be done in automation installation script. [Dump mysqlDB link](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php)

**Solution 3 (not recommended)**:

You can copy entire mysql data in directory and paste to other machine mysql directory. Based on my experience, never success.  [But look at this guy link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5933)

There is a pro and cons using embedded SQL or centralize SQL. If you stick with this kind of architecture, you should consider use embedded SQL like you mention.